# How I can update my ZFS file system?

Tags: kernel, updates, zfs, dkms, source

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on Root ZFS. In my previous post I've described problem where Wi-Fi connection drops for all devices that are connected to my router such as phones, tablets, laptops at boot and at shutdown when network service tries to establish my Ethernet connection. I've tried everything to solve this problem, and I still didn't find the solution.

I've heard that installing new version of Linux kernel is the solution. So, I've tried different versions of kernels. I want to install Kernel 5.19 - I think this will be the solution, because I've heard that "Kernel 5.19 was released with major network features", so maybe there is a fix for problem that I've encountered.

Okay, I will be clear. I have zfs installed on my machine version of 2.1.5 which doesn't supports linux kernels higher than 5.18.
So I need to update my zfs from 2.1.5 to 2.1.6 or at least 2.1.12, but how I can do this? I've tried to find ANY information about this, and didn't found anything.

Should I instead of updating my ZFS file system just install another version of ZFS modules to new kernel by using DKMS? If so, then how I can do this? Should I compile custom DKMS package from ZFS sources to make it working for installing though DKMS, ZFS modules into new installed kernel?

Answer (score 1):

The hwe kernel for 22.04 seems to be 5.19, so just install linux-generic-hwe-22.04 which should have zfs integrated as all Ubuntu kernels do.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and after installation and booting into new installed kernel I am getting error: 
ALERT: ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu does not exist. Dropping to shell!

Comment: Probably need to do a zpool import.  I don't know if you can do it from that initramfs shell, if not boot a live CD.